# python or bash Code to empty subfolder contents into main folder and delete empty subfolders

Tags: python, bash, shell

In my music directory I have subfolders for each individual artist and album. I would like to make an automation script that goes into each subfolder and cuts and pastes all of the contents into my main music directory. After the script has moved the music, I would like for it to delete the empty subfolders. Something in a python or shell script would be awesome. Any ideas?

Comment: cut? paste? The command you want is `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command will list all the files in subdirectories of the named directory. So:

```
find . -type f
```

That will produce a list of file names. To move all those files to the current directory,

```
mv `find . -type f` .
```

Finally, to recursively delete any empty subdirectories,

```
find . -type d | xargs rmdir
```

If any of your file or directory names have spaces in them, things get a lot more ... interesting. But if that's the case, you can use the above as a starting point.

Comment: The find command worked excellent to produce the list of files however when I tried to move them I got this error "mv: invalid option -- 'W'
Try `mv --help' for more information."

Comment: It sounds like you have files whose names start with `-`. You should be able to tell `mv` to quit processing options using `mv -- \`find . -type f\` .`

Comment: Don't use `mv` with `find` in a command substitution. That will fail for filenames that include spaces (which music files are quit likely to have). Use `find ... -exec mv ... \;` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 mv ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/music    # wherever your music directory is
mv */* .
rmdir * 2>/dev/null
```